# Angular Directive: Make submit button directive listen to form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have a bunch of forms in my project and all of them have a set of specific validation expressions. On top of that I have also a loading element attached to it so it makes pretty hard to reuse that button throughout the project. With that in mind I figured I could use a directive instead. The problem is that when I pass in my expressions through attributes it does not update/validate as user inputs data. Basically it just sits with the attribute like if it was a string and not an expression.

In a nutshell what I've been trying to achieve is something like this:

```
<submit-button label="My Label" validate="!myForm.$valid"></submit-button>
```

Which will return something like that:

```
<button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">My Label</button>
```

Here's a basic isolated template on jsfiddle of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/lucasbittar/8m992bet/3/

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this in that version of Angular is to utilize a two-way attribute binding on your directive. Bind the `validate` attribute/scope property to your expression, and reference that in the `ngDisabled` directive.

An important thing to note is that `ngDisabled` (and other `ng`-prefixed directives, IIRC) operate on expressions directly, so you shouldn't use double-brackets to interpolate them.

Directive code becomes:

```
function submitButton () {
  var submit = {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: ['^form'],
    template: '<button ng-disabled="validate">{{ label }}</button>',
    scope: {
      validate: '='
    },
    link: link
  }
  return submit;

  function link (scope, el, attr, formCtrl) {
    scope.label = attr.label;
  }
}
```

Check out the working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8m992bet/6/

Note that if you wanted, you could also mimic the above using an inherited scope on your directive combined with `scope.$watch`, but using a two-way binding is easier.

Also note that on Angular 1.5 you can utilize a one-way binding on a directive using `<` instead of `=`.

Comment: it worked perfectly! thanks you so much for the assistance!